# How to know when the playControllerBar of moviePlayer will be dismiss?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, iphone-sdk-3.2

as the title,when i play movie using moviePlayer I want to know when the playControllerBar will be dismiss,so that i can control my view added in moviePlayer .
Is there anyone know that?
Tell me ,thanks .

Comment: I work at Iphone os3.2,the tag Iphone os3.0 must be a mistake,i really want know how did it work at Iphone os3.2. 
The playControllerBar is what i meant the bar has pause,play,forward,backward,and playback rate bar .

Comment: MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand you correctly. 
I assume that what you want to do is:

1. play a movie
2. add a custom view (overlay) on top of the (running) movie.

assuming what i just wrote down, I think you have to consider the following things:

1. adding a custom overlay on top of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is (as far as I'm concerned) only allowed/possible if the standard player controls are set to none:

   ```
   [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
   ```
2. adding your custom overlay on top of the player is basically the same `addSubview` procedure as on any other view

   ```
   [moviePlayerViewController.view addSubview:overlay];
   ```

**the above code / concept will work on 3.2 and later, as i just read now you're obviously developing for 3.0**

rather then deleting the first part of my answer i will now explain how to achieve the same effect on 3.0

on 3.0 it's a bit trickier (as you sure know by now). 
MPMoviePlayerController is not a view Controller and works only in fullscreen-mode. **Once the movie starts playing, the keyWindow changes**! so We make use of that by implementing the following:

1) within your Class that encapsulates the MPMoviePlayerController, start listening to the `UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` by doing the following:

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                             selector: @selector(keyWindowChanged:) 
                                                 name: UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification 
                                               object: nil];
```

2) withing your `keyWindowChanged:` Method you can add your overlay, the following snipplet is exactly how I implemented it:

```
- (void)keyWindowChanged: (id) sender {

//NSLog(@"keyWindowChanged");
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self name: UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object: nil];
UIWindow *moviePlayerWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

[moviePlayerWindow addSubview: overlayController.view];
[overlayController performSelector:@selector(fadeIn)]; 

}
```

again, this only works if the `MovieControllMode` is "hidden" by doing that:

```
[newMPController setMovieControlMode: MPMovieControlModeHidden];
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: it really helps me a lot ,it's very nice of you ,thank you ,good man~